# How to add wysiwyg editor in "HTML" pyrocms widget

Tags: pyrocms

I would say if it's possible to add wysiwyg editor (CKeditor) in "HTML" pyrocms widget. I'm trying in this way, but it doesn't work:

1) In "system/cms/modules/widgets/controllers/admin.php", I've changed __constructor method:

```
    $this->template
      ->set_partial('shortcuts', 'admin/partials/shortcuts')
      ->append_metadata(js('widgets.js', 'widgets'))
      ->append_metadata(css('widgets.css', 'widgets'));
```

to this

```
    $this->template
      ->set_partial('shortcuts', 'admin/partials/shortcuts')
      ->append_metadata(js('widgets.js', 'widgets'))
      ->append_metadata(css('widgets.css', 'widgets'))
      ->append_metadata($this->load->view('fragments/wysiwyg', $this->data, TRUE));
```

2) In "system/cms/widgets/html/views/form.php", I've changed

```
<?php echo form_textarea(array('name'=>'html', 'value' => $options['html'])); ?>
```

to this

```
<?php echo form_textarea(array('id'=>'html', 'name'=>'html', 'value' => $options['html'], 'class' => 'wysiwyg-simple')); ?>
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution: you can read it here http://pyrocms.com/forums/topics/view/2552

Comment: hello. maybe you got more info on this? I have added to widget constructor: $this->template->append_metadata($this->load->view('fragments/wysiwyg', array(), true));

I see the JS loaded in header, but how now to bind the ckeditor, when we load the ckeditor? class is OK, somehow need to trigger the ckeditor init on EDIT